# How can I implement public key encryption/decryption?

Tags: android, encryption, public-key-encryption

So I'm making an application that will store some sensitive data such as password and user location details (longitude and latitude) in a database.

I have been able to encrypt the password using a one way encryption. (Did not make it myself don't worry.) But as for the user location, I need to be able to decrypt this data as I will need to re-use it.

I am aware this can be achieved using `Public Key Encryption`, I just don't know how to go about it. I have read and understood the concept, but can't seem to find ways in which I can do this. As in where my public key is placed, where my private key is placed and such.

Sorry if this question is broad, I'm really lost and can't find the information I'm looking for on the internet.

Comment: I suppose it's because of all the cookies but when I feed your question title to a search engine I get lots of promising results. And a key might be placed in something like a keystore. Did you try searching for "Android keystore"?

Comment: Why do you think you need public key cryptography?  Unless you have a **very** good reason, you probably don't need it.  Symmetric encryption would do just fine here.

Comment: @0X0nosugar - Wow, I just typed the question and got good info. I suppose it's because whenever I search on Google, I search using keywords and never seem to get anywhere. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to have a look at the [Android keystore system](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore).

Tutorial how to use a key stored in the keystore to encrypt/decrypt: https://medium.com/@josiassena/using-the-android-keystore-system-to-store-sensitive-information-3a56175a454b

(You could use symmetric cryptography to encrypt/decrypt your data and encrypt/decrypt the key for the symmetric cryptography with help of the Android keystore.)